# Using Charles to debug webhook running on Digital Ocean Droplet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, charles-proxy

First time using Charles and I'm completely confused. I've watched [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nihC1xW1eNI) and read thru many a [tutorial](http://www.ericfeminella.com/blog/2011/08/22/map-remote-in-charles/) and I'm still drawing a blank.

My JSON response to a POST request suddenly stopped working, and I can't figure out why. The JSON is valid, so I'm thinking something is up with my headers.

I want to view my header and I'm thinking I need to use the "Map Remote" feature of Charles, but hell I'm not even sure about that.. My situation is that I have a webhook that gets hit with a `POST` request at:

```
http://mine.com/webhook/receive
```

There is a Rails app that lives there on a Digital Ocean Droplet, and processes the request and renders a response like this:

```
render json: my_response
```

I THINK I can use Charles to sit between the request and response so I can view my header. I've mapped my local machine to my remote service like this:
[image: My Charles Settings]

But I'm not seeing any traffic come thru.

Is Charles even the right tool to try and view my response to the webhook? And if so, what feature should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a messy workaround, but I dare to post as there has been no other answer:

You could run Charlesproxy on a separate machine in the same network, and configure that machine's 8888 port as the web proxy for the machine on which you develop. That way Charles will record your requests.

Edit:
Just seeing that the Charlesproxy's faqs answer a question very similar to yours:
[Localhost traffic doesn't appear in Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/#qa_172)